# Blender 3.0.1: Can't Move Objects in Object Mode

Tags: transforms, object-mode

I know this has been asked and "answered" elsewhere, but still...

I'm using Blender 3.0.1-2 in Arch Linux, and I'm unable to transform an object unless I'm in edit mode. The only exception to this is the camera and light source, which I can grab and move around.

I've searched around for answers to this issue and everything points to unchecking the origins, locations, and parents checkboxes under Options>Transform>Affect Only, however, they are already unchecked. Also looking under Item>Transform all of my X,Y,Z coordinates for Location, Rotation, and Scale are unlocked, so should be editable.

[image]

Similarly, if I'm working with a plane or text, I can't just select the object press "G" and then a letter corresponding to an axis to quickly adjust it.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is happens if you restore factory settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ah just solved this exact same problem. Turned out to be an NVIDIA driver problem (weirdly enough). Basically, I wasn't using the GPU on my linux machine (I checked settings > details and saw that the graphics section said "llvmpipe" and not something about my gpu). To resolve this, I installed the nvidia drivers for it (`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515`), rebooted my machine, and verified that my computer now uses my gpu. And now blender works fine. I have no idea how my gpu has anything to do with objects not moving in blender though.